# simple css media queries not working

Tags: android, css, media-queries

The following web page displays correctly on desktop but I can't figure out why it's not working on a android phone(the color of the text is always blue):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media screen { body { color: blue; } }
            @media handheld { body { color: red; } }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a test!
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested on:

- Android: 4.0.4
- Standard android web browser: 4.0.4-S7562XXALJ4
- Chrome: 25.0.1364.169
- Firefox: 19.0.2

On all the mobile browsers the option to display web page as on computer screen has been disabled. The online web pages that use media queries work correctly.

I've also tried only screen/not screen pair and it still does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by targeting the view port size

```
@media screen { body { color: blue; } }
@media only screen 
    and (max-width : 420px) { 
    /* Styles */
    body { color: red; }
}
```

Modify the "max-width" according your targeted device view port

Comment: Thanks, this works. I've avoided going on this route because it's a hackish fix :(, but it will do.